# Error while attempting to install Python 3.8.2 on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am using Windows 7 64 bit and when I attempt to run the executable installer for Python 3.8.2 I get an error stating that I need to install windows service pack 1 to continue. I already have windows service pack 1 installed on this drive, I've double checked and reinstalled it but this has not fixed the issue.

This is what's in the error log:

> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i001: Burn v3.11.1.2318, Windows v6.1
>   (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path:
>   C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp{4C6C4ED2-212B-4FA8-BD34-C5891FEA4006}.cr\python-3.8.2-amd64.exe
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'ShortVersion' to value '3.8'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'ShortVersionNoDot' to value '38'
>   [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'WinVer' to value '3.8'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'WinVerNoDot' to value '38'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'InstallAllUsers' to value '0'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'InstallLauncherAllUsers' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'TargetDir' to value ''
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'DefaultAllUsersTargetDir' to value
>   '[ProgramFiles64Folder]Python[WinVerNoDot]'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'TargetPlatform' to value 'x64'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'DefaultJustForMeTargetDir' to  value
>   '[LocalAppDataFolder]Programs\Python\Python[WinVerNoDot]'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'OptionalFeaturesRegistryKey' to value
>   'Software\Python\PythonCore[WinVer]\InstalledFeatures'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'TargetDirRegistryKey' to value
>   'Software\Python\PythonCore[WinVer]\InstallPath'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'DefaultCustomTargetDir' to value ''
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'InstallAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'InstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'CustomInstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value
>   '[InstallLauncherAllUsersState]'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'TargetDirState' to value 'enabled'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'CustomBrowseButtonState' to value 'enabled'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_core' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_exe' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_dev' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_lib' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_test' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_doc' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_tools' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_tcltk' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_pip' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_launcher' to value '-1 '
>   [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'Include_launcherState' to value 'enabled'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_symbols' to value '0'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Include_debug' to value '0'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'LauncherOnly' to value '0'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'DetectedLauncher' to value '0'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'DetectedOldLauncher' to value '0'
>   [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'AssociateFiles' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'Shortcuts' to value '1'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'PrependPath' to value '0'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'CompileAll' to value '0'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing numeric variable
>   'SimpleInstall' to value '0'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Initializing string variable
>   'SimpleInstallDescription' to value ''
>   [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i009: Command Line:
>   '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\python-3.8.2-amd64.exe
>   -burn.filehandle.attached=180 -burn.filehandle.self=188'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value
>   'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\python-3.8.2-amd64.exe'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Python
>   3.8.2 (64-bit)_20200410051605.log'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleName' to value 'Python 3.8.2 (64-bit)'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Setting string variable
>   'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Python Software Foundation'
>
> [1B0C:1AAC][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Setting numeric variable
>   'CRTInstalled' to value 1
>
> [1B0C:1D88][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Did not find
>   C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\unattend.xml
>
> [1B0C:1D88][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Setting string variable
>   'ActionLikeInstalling' to value  'Installing'
>
> [1B0C:1D88][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Setting string variable
>   'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'
>
> [1B0C:1D88][2020-04-10T05:16:05]i000: Setting version variable
>   'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '3.8.2150.0'
>
> [1B0C:1D88][2020-04-10T05:16:05]e000: Detected Windows 7 SP1 without
>   KB2533623
>
> [1B0C:1D88][2020-04-10T05:16:05]e000: KB2533623 update is required to
>   continue.

Comment: Hi! I am not an active Windows user, but have you looked into installing update `KB2533623` from the update center? To me, it looks like that particular Python version requires a certain Windows update to be installed. It even explicitly tells you that  it *Detected Windows 7 SP1 **without** KB2533623*

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, that update should not be related to SP1. I believe it is a standalone update. Try installing it from the official Microsoft website [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=26767)

Answer (score 0):

I have observed that versions above 3.7.2 require more that just the SP1 update. Looking at your log files, you will find that it requires you to install the update `KB2533623`. Unless you fulfill the all the prerequisites for the installation, you wouldn't be able to continue with it. Install the appropriate updates as referred to by the setup/log-file and try again.

It is probable that the Service Pack 1 update might have not installed properly into the system. You would need to retry installing the updates. I am afraid to tell you that official free support and updates to Windows 7 have been discontinued since the onset of 2020, so you might have a hard time finding the correct update.

Sometimes, the update unexpectedly fails to install properly. If nothings else works, the service pack version may be fixed through the registry, but at one's own risk as it might lead to consequences.

Handling the registry is dangerous, so proceed at your own risk.

- Open the registry editor.
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Windows`.
- Modify the hexadecimal value of `CSDVersion` to 100 for SP1, 200 for SP2, and 300 to SP3.
- Restart the PC.